# Reusing OAuth from one canvas app in another

Tags: oauth2, canvas

I have a few canvas apps that show pages from the same external system in Salesforce. I was wondering if there's anyway we can use OAuth from a single canvas app in all the other places, otherwise, I'd have to configure a different client secret for requests to each of these different apps.

I have tried the straight forward approach of configuring one Connected App with OAuth and not enabling OAuth on the others, but it doesn't work. I get a `Signed Request tampered with` error.